# ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error while communicating from angular server(letsencrypt cert installed) to node server(self signed certs installed)

Tags: mean-stack, lets-encrypt

I have my angular server installed with let'sencrypt certificate issued with a host name. and back end node servers are running with public ips with self signed certificates installed.

am getting this error(net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID) while accessing my application in the browser. and browser also shows "not secure".

thanks for the help.

Comment: Do 2 server have separate domain names? Can you put the back-end node server on the same LAN as the angular server?

Comment: angular server has domain name. but backend node server does not have any domain name. both are digital ocean droplets , so we can't have them in the same  LAN.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

I edited my answer.

If you can setup OpenSSH server on your node.js back-end, then you can make your angular server forward requests through SSH tunnel to the node.js server.

First, setup a daemon to run the following command:

```
ssh -N -L <port-#A>:<port-on-node-server> <node-server-address>
```

This forwards connection to port-#A on the angular server to the specified port on the node server. The first time connection is made, the public key of the node server is saved. I recommend setup authorized keys on the node server, so that your angular server can communicate with the node server using public-key cryptography.